# Datapump REMAP_DATA using another column

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, datapump, expdp

I need to mask first and last name.  Our requirement is to use the first name only.  How can I access the FIRST_NM field when masking the LAST_NM?

LAST_NM=substr(FIRST_NM,1,4)||'LAST'

select T.EE_FIRST_NM, T.EE_LAST_NM from MY_TABLE

Original:
Lakshmanan    Ramaswamy

Expected Result:
LaksFIRST     LaksLAST

Comment: What version of oracle?  Please edit your question and add a version tag like `oracle-12g` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `REMAP_DATA` is available from Oracle 11g on.  The issue is the `REMAP_DATA` parameter takes one column as input and a PL/SQL package/function to process that data; so you wouldn't really be able to figure out what first name goes with what last name.  There is a good [DataPump REMAP_DATA PDF](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/datapump11g2009-transform-133936.pdf) on a sample package & function would work; but it won't solve your problem.

What you could do, depending on your Oracle version, is define a virtual column named `LAST_NAME_MASKED` on your `MY_TABLE` that contains a function to do your `substr`, and then exclude the `LAST_NM` column from the DataPump export.